# ./gradle : The term './gradle' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: flutter, gradle

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uq76W.png)
PS C:\my progect\android> ./gradle assembleRelease
./gradle : The term './gradle' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- ./gradle assembleRelease

PS C:\my progect\android> ./gradle assembleRelease
./gradle : The term './gradle' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- ./gradle assembleRelease

Comment: Unless "gradle.exe" is sitting in that folder, which I doubt, you just want `gradle assembleRelease`.  You find it on the PATH.  The "dot slash" says "execute this file which is in the current directory."

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.